# create a variable that is in sync with a files content in bash

Tags: bash

In bash i'd like to read in a variable that is constantly in sync with a files contents.

how can I get this done?

```
echo "test" > /tmp/test
value=$(</tmp/test)

echo $value
test

echo "test2" > /tmp/test
echo $value
test    # Id 'like this to return test2
```

Comment: Not possible. What's your use-case? There might be a work-around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Fravadona comments, not possible.

Using a function is a workaround:

```sh
value() { cat /tmp/test; }

echo "test" > /tmp/test
echo $(value)   # => test

echo "test2" > /tmp/test
echo $(value)   # => test2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do something like what you want.  The basic idea is to run a background process to monitor the file for changes and send signals to your program when they occur.  A signal handler in your program can update the variable value when it receives a signal.

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates the idea:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

# Turn on monitor mode (job control).
# (This causes background processes to run in separate process groups, making
# it easy to kill a background process and all processes created by it.)
set -o monitor

# Send a SIGUSR1 signal to the given PID ($1) whenever the contents of the
# given file ($2) change
function send_sigusr1_on_file_change
{
    local -r pid=$1
    local -r file=$2

    inotifywait -m -q -e modify -- "$file" \
        |   while read -r _; do
                kill -USR1 "$pid"
            done

    return 0
}

# Initialize the test file and the 'value' variable to empty
: >/tmp/test
value=''

# Update 'value' with the contents of '/tmp/test' whenever a
# SIGUSR1 signal is received.
trap 'value=$(< /tmp/test)' SIGUSR1

# Run a background process to scan for changes in '/tmp/test' and send
# SIGUSR1 signals to this process ($$) when they occur.
send_sigusr1_on_file_change "$$" /tmp/test &
signaller_pid=$!

# Set a trap to kill the background process when this program exits.
# (Negating the PID causes all processes in the process group associated with
# the background process to be killed.  This is to prevent subprocesses
# created by the background process (e.g. 'inotifywait') from continuing to
# run after it is killed.)
trap 'kill -- "-$signaller_pid"' EXIT

# Wait for the signaller loop to start signalling changes
sleep 1

echo 'test' >/tmp/test
sleep 0.01  # Wait for the change to the file to be detected and signalled

printf '%s\n' "$value"

echo 'test2' >/tmp/test
sleep 0.01  # Wait for the change to the file to be detected and signalled

printf '%s\n' "$value"
```

On my Linux test system the program consistently outputs:

```
test
test2
```

- Because there is a small delay between the file changing and the variable being updated I've had to add calls to `sleep` to make it work reliably.  That may be a problem for you.
- I've used [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to efficiently scan for changes in the file.  You might need to use an alternative depending on what is available, or can be installed, on your systems.  You could also use a polling loop, but that would be more resource-hungry, and probably lead to longer delays in updating the variable.
- See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I used `printf` instead of `echo` for printing the variable value.  (`echo` is OK for printing (some) fixed strings.)